# How to perform a search using the Desk API v2

Tags: c#, oauth, restsharp

Has any one had any success using Desk's public API to do searches for either customers or companies? I am using the RestSharp library to submit requests, which works fine for creating new companies or pulling individual cases by ID. Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do.

```
RestClient client = new RestClient();

client.Authenticator = RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(Configuration.ApiKey, Configuration.SiteKey, Configuration.Token, Configuration.TokenSecret);
client.BaseUrl = "https://imathlete.desk.com/api/v2";

string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "q", "my company" }
});

RestRequest request = new RestRequest {
    Method = Method.GET
    , Resource = "companies/search"
    , RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
};

request.AddBody(json);

RestResponse response = (RestResponse)client.Execute(request);
string data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response.RawBytes);
```

I've tried switching out the "q" in the request body for either "name" or "domain," but the response is always the same:

```
{"message":"Invalid search parameters"}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change

```
Resource = "companies/search"
```

to

```
Resource = "companies/search?"
```

Also be sure to URI encode your query string

debugging tips:

- Use the [PostMan chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), other browsers might have
  similar tools
- Inspect the network XHR requests sent by the Desk
  search box in the Desk app.